# Java MongoDB Read ~5 million record collection quickly

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to read a collection of roughly 5 million records in around 1.5 - 2 minutes using the java mongodb driver. Each record is roughly 1900 bytes. The collection only has an index on the generated "id" and the entire data set fits in memory. Essentially, all of these records are being stored in a large array list via the java application. I have tweaked the JVM increasing the memory and tried to use the parallelscan option, but have not had any luck reading the data within the desired time frame. I've been able to hit read the entire collection into the array list at around 5 minutes with the following. No filtering is being done.

```
ParallelScanOptions parallelScanOptions = ParallelScanOptions
                .builder()
                .numCursors(4)
                .batchSize(250000)
                .build();
```

Comment: Where is this data coming from?  It sounds like about 60 MB/s which is expected from a HDD, and reasonable for a 1 Gb/s network. If it is in memory on the same machine, that is on the slow side.

Comment: The mongodb instance is running on the same server that the script runs. The mongodb data is located on a SSD and the memory is roughly 40Gbps (via my system admin). The server has 256GB of memory and the utilization of memory is only at around 20GB. If you have any suggestion to verify that it is being pulled from memory, then please provide details.

Comment: `gbps` = `grams bits per second` I assume you mean `GiB` = `gibi-bytes` or `1024^3 bytes` Or do you mean the maximum transfer rate is `40 GB/s` Reading it more than once without any sign of reading from disk means it came from memory.